# How to extract a tag by classname and all its children tags

Tags: javascript

How can I extract tags by classname and all their children tags?

There are Tags with a specific class name and with some  tags in it. These tags I want to extract and put them into an array. Here is my code:

```
function getTagByClassname() {

    var bodyContent = document.body.innerHTML
    var tagsArray = [];


    window.alert(bodyContent);
    for(var i = 0; i<5;i++) {

        tagsArray[i] =  bodyContent.getElementsByClassName("classy");
        window.alert(tagsArray[i]);

    }
```

I want to have the content of each tag with the class name "classy" in an arrayindex . Something like that:

tagsArray[0] has the content:

```
<table class="classy" width="500px">
    <tr>
      <td >
         <div width="80%" style="background-color:yellow;">Green</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `.innerHTML` gives you a *string*, you can't call `getElementsByClassName` on a string

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks, but how else can I do that? I tried without .innerHTML, only with document.body. But it also failed.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Seems to work just fine here https://jsfiddle.net/ahesz67j/